# Pass variables through playa loop to use in an embed?

Tags: playa, embeds

Currently I have a a channel page entry that then goes through a playa of secondary entries.
I'd like to pass some of the parent's data like page title and description to the embdeds.

My code looks similar to this:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {exp:playa:children field="content"}
            {embed="some_widget" entry_id="{entry_id}" variable="{title}" description="{description}"}
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I'd like to pass my embed:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"  title="{title}" description="{description}"}
    <!--test-->
    {title}
    <br>        
    {description}           
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Right now, it does embed the widget. But none of the information is passed along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the embed syntax quite right. Passing `{embed:entry_id}` is correct, as that tells the `channel:entries` tag which entry to load. But there are no `channel:entries` parameters called `title` or `description`.

Instead, simply use them in the same way you used `{embed:entry_id}`.

Also - in your example, `{title}` will actually be the title of the *child* entry, not the parent. To use the parent's title inside of the Playa tag, use a `var_prefix` on `playa:children` - this will prevent `{title}` from being replaced by Playa.

So your ending code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="foo"}
    {exp:playa:children field="content" var_prefix="widget"}
            {embed="some_widget" entry_id="{widget:entry_id}" title="{title}" description="{description}"}
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then in your embed:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" dynamic="no"}
    <!--test-->
    {embed:title}
    <br>        
    {embed:description}           
{/exp:channel:entries}
```